# Multi-objective optimization but the function equation is unknown?

Tags: optimization, mathematical-optimization

Firstly, I am totally out of my expertise zone so please bear with me.

I developed a fluid dynamic engine with 5 exposed parameters (say A,B,C,D,E). When you give this engine these 5 parameters, it does magic and give out a value 'Z'.

I want to write a script which can explore which combinations of A-E give lowest (or close to lowest) value of Z.

I know optimization algorithm exists, but from all of my search for examples, they use some function.

So I guess my function would simply be minimize Z? But where do A-E go?

Comment: I think you are confused. Just minimizing Z does not give you a multi-objective optimization problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really an answer, but some questions and ideas that might help you think through the best way to address this. We have no understanding of how big a range of values needs to be explored for those parameters, or how Z behaves, so this is very vague...

If you look at the values of Z for given values of A...E, does the value of Z jump around a lot for small changes on the parameter values, or does the Z value change reasonably smoothly?

If the Z value is not too eratic you could try some kind of gradient descent approach using calculated values of Z for some values of the parameters to approximate the gradient - suppose changing the value of 'A' from 1 to 2 gives a better change in the Z value than a similar size change in the other parameters, then try other values of A while keeping the other parameters fixed until you find a value of A that gives the best value of Z. Then try changing the other parameter values to see which one gives the steepest descent and try to find some better value for that parameter. Repeat this process until you can't find any improvement and you will have found a (local) minimum. You could then start at a different place in your parameter space and try again - you will probably find several local minima, and may just choose the best of those. Not provably optimal but may be good enough. Of course you can get clever and use things like conjugate gradients, Newton-Raphson or similar if Z is smooth enough.

If the Z values are very eratic, then you might have to just do some sampling of the possible combinations of A...E to get values of Z and choose the best you can find. Again you might do that in some systematic way (e.g. points on a grid in your parameter space) or entirely at random, or a combination of both.

If you find that there are 'clusters' of good solutions with similar values of the parameters then maybe some kind of local search would help - the idea is that there is often a better solution in the local neighbourhood of a known good solution. So maybe try perturbing your parameter values a bit from a known solution to see if that can lead to a better solution - either by some gradient descent method or by random sampling.

Unfortunately, if your Z calculation is complex, then any method using it as a black box will likely be slow as it will need to be re-evaluated many times.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Genetic Algorithm, where your chromosomes are formed with the 5 candidate values of the variables you have to optimize, to minimize Z, and your optimization/fitness "function" is the simulation itself outputting Z.

Other viable alternatives are Particle Swarm Optimization algorithm or Ant Colony Optimization. All of those are usable algortihms for that kind of optimization problem.